# Django - Authenticate against existing DB

Tags: python, django, authentication

Apologies if this is simple or my terminology is off, this is my first django project. I haven't been able to find a similar solution for this online.

I have an existing application, with a postgres DB where I authenticate my users. I have wrote an application in Django to interact with some tables and display info to the user. I  would like to use Django to login and track User sessions against this DB. so I can use the features like

`{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

but I don't want to use the migrate command so I don't want to change the existing DB. I can access the table where the account info is as I created a model for it.

I see you can use remote user logon param but I cant find any sample or guide on  how to use it and am completely lost.

Right now I create a login form in the views page. Then get the username and password that is entered, but I don't know what to do next. Also would need to hash the password. Is there a libray in djano that will do that for the app.

Any pointers or online guides for this would be appreciated.

Here is the views for login

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.data['account_email']
        password = form.data['account_password']

        user = authenticate(username=email)

        if user.check_password(password):
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('myapp:cust_select')
        else:
            # Username and password did not match
            raise ValidationError('Invalid Username/Password')

return render(request, 'myapp/login.html', {'form' : form}
```

backends.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UserAuthBackend(object):    
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            account = get_user_model()

            user = account.objects.get(account_email=username)
            if user:
                return user
        except account.DoesNotExist:
            print "account not found"
        return None 

    def get_user(self, user_id):
       try:
          account = get_user_model()
          return account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
       except User.DoesNotExist:
          return None
```

models.py

```
class Accounts(AbstractUser):
    account_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    account_email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_password = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.account_email 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'accounts'
```

settings.py

```
 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'myapp.backends.UserAuthBackend', )
```

Its keeps exiting with the same error in the sql query. 
    column accounts.password does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT "accounts"."password", "accounts"."last_login", "acco...

It doesnt appear to be using my Account model. It does select it from that table but how can i get it to stop requesting `accounts.password` and `accounts.last_login` as they dont exist in y Accounts model

Comment: When a form is valid, you should get the data using its `cleaned_data` dictionary, not the `data` dictionary. Also I assume passwords aren't saved plain-text in your DB, but hashed, so you can't fetch accounts just by using `account_password=password` (Django has an `authenticate` method to calculate the hash and check against the one saved in the db).

Comment: But I think it would be hard to do the authentication directly in Django if the user data is saved in a db that wasn't created with Django. The [authentication backend mechanism of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#other-authentication-sources) allows you to call an external API to authenticate your user, by writing your own authentication backend, which would probably be easier (assuming you already have a server that can authenticate a user based on username/password).

Answer (score 0):

For [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/)
Note: You need to do try, catch to get this code working

```
def login(request):
    form = LoginForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.data['account_email']
            password = form.data['account_password']

            # First authenticate
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None  :
                # Succeed, now log user in
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('myapp:select')
            else:
                # Username and password did not match
                raise ValidationError('Invalid Username/Password')

     return render(request, 'myapp/login.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: Do I have to write a class for the authenticate method? I imagine it should be validated against the Accounts model but how would I check this out? Also how to hash the password?

Comment: You do not need to worry about model. It will be validated against Accounts model if Accounts model is a custom user model. Otherwise, it will be validated against default User model. You will not need to hash password. Django will do it for you. If you need to set password, you can use django's utility set_password given in docs.

Comment: Ok I've read some tutorials on Custom user models. Thanks for your help. I will try this method